# how to force browser to validate wellformedness of XHTML5

Tags: xml, xhtml

I've been searching for a while and have seen many different examples of how to declare a file as a XHTML5. So it's supposed to be something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   blabla
</html>
```

Is there a way to force the browser to reject a file that is not well formed xml? I tried with this error but it still rendered (in Brave):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect stroke="black" fill="blue" x="45px" y="45px" width="200px" height="100px" stroke-width="2" />
<a>
</svg>
</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that if you're loading the main page, then this can't be done. You can always get the document via an `XmlHttpRequest` in which case you can ensure it is parsed by the XML parser, and is therefore well-formed XML. But this still won't give you DTD-based validation (XML parsers in the browser don't do DTDs).

Comment: Thanks, I'm more in the well-formedness than the DTD. I'll need to check the DTD later on. I'm just trying to get my head around the XML + HTML5 duo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers, like any other XML consumers are not required to reject a resource that's not XML well-formed, although they may do so if they prefer. They are only required to stop parsing the input on encountering a well-formedness error. To make the browser use its XML parser to parse the input, set the HTTP header `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`.

Note also the mismatch in your question between title and body. Validity and Well-formedness are different things.

Comment: Thanks, it's the application then that must set this. Thanks for the cue on the mismatch. It is indeed different things. For now, I'm looking at well-formedness.

Comment: @MusicAndCode Which application are you talking about here? If you have actual HTML files, the way to change them into XHTML is to change the extensions.

Comment: @MrLister - That's really not accurate. Changing the extension works for local files, but for web resources it depends on the server configuration and the application it is running. Typically, a server will be configured to send files with a .xhtml extension as `application/xhtml+xml`, but it need not be like that. A server could be configured to send files with a .html extension  as `application/xhtml+xml` is desired. In my case, I have a .NET application that uses a .ashx extension and the application determines which content type to use by sniffing the request header data.

Comment: @Alohci True, this is easily configurable, and you might run into trouble assuming that settings are what you expect they would be. But in the vast majority of servers, the default is as you say, and an .xhtml file uploaded there will behave the same in the browser as one loaded locally. Then there's no need for a beginner to jump to hoops trying to change the MIME type manually from within the file.